# How well does Google Play Books support page-oriented css? (i.e., page breaks)

Tags: css, google-play-books, page-break

While testing ebooks, I have been finding deficiencies in css support in Google Play Books.

Namely, this doesn't work:

```
h2 {
page-break-before: always;           
}
```

GPB's support for embedded fonts is also  inconsistent.

The epub3 test suite seems to show ample support for epub3 
http://epubtest.org/evaluation/1/ but it doesn't get granular about css support that should have existed in epub2.

I'm assuming the answer is no, but does anyone know of a way to force a page break using css only in GPB (instead of using separate html files)?

Also, what's the best way to stay informed about css support for GPB? I have generally been happy with GPB's support for CSS, but this bug caught me offguard. From what I can tell, GPB doesn't have any  formatting guide or even a forum specifically to address formatting questions by content creators.

Comment: I ended with separate html files. I think there is no other way by now.