# Resize readium document if content body has changed

Tags: ebook-readers, epub, html

I have an interactive ebook that hides answers from the learner until he/she clicks a **Show** button.

The show function then toggles an div element between `display:none` and `display:block`. All answers are initialized with `display:none`.

This causes no issues in iBooks or Adobe DE, but in readium the scrollview that contains the html does not resize when the div is shown. The images below should explain a bit better.

The bottom of the page when the answer is hidden:
[image: The bottom of the page when the answer is hidden]

The bottom of the page when the answer is shown
[image: The bottom of the page when the answer is shown]

Notice the extra content barely visible below the answer block, the scrollbar is at the bottom and cannot scroll down any further.
Once I manually resize redium, the scrollview is automatically fixed.

Is there a way for me to force the size update on the readium scrollview using JS?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need Readium support? I'd be far more interested in how things render in Google Play Books or when converted to Kindle.

Comment: **@Mome:** It looks like you used the Chrome Readium extension for testing, which is not 100% epub3 compatible, because of number of unresolved bugs. 

If your book passes epubcheck and works in ADE and iBooks, most users shouldn't experience problems,


You might want to test your file also on eInk readers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much ability to answer your question (especially without seeing your code or knowing the required space in the viewport to hide or display).

I'm aware of and have occasionally tested things on Readium. But I never had a use case for supporting Readium for epubs.

If you support  ibooks and ADE, that's covering a lot of ground. I assume it means you have also tested on Google Play Books.

**Update:** I see that Bluefire has released an ios reader based on readium. So that counts for something. That is still a sliver of reading audience.

You said this is related to resizing. I have noticed that some apps have resizing flakiness. But resizing is something you usually do on a PC browser, not a mobile device. I would worry about whether this issue shows up on mobile devices.

Let me mention that Google Play Books also has  problems with regard to css related to page size. See my previous question here: [How well does Google Play Books support page-oriented css? (i.e., page breaks)](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6539/how-well-does-google-play-books-support-page-oriented-css-i-e-page-breaks) ).   If Readium is based on Chrome code base, I have to wonder if this issue is rooted in Chrome instead of Readium or GPB.

Comment: **@idiotprogrammer:** _Update: I see that Bluefire has released an ios reader based on readium_  FYI: Bluefire Reader is based on Adobe RMSDK. I.e., the same library that is also used by Adobe Digital Editions (ADE). The current [ADE Android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.digitaleditions&hl=en) is based on  RMSDK 12.5, i.e. the same version used by the ADE desktop app. (The current Bluefire Reader Android version uses an older RMSDK version.)

Comment: NEMO XXX How right you are. June 2016 Readium made an announcement that BlueFire released an app based on Readium SDK. That does not mean it is abandoning Adobe just yet... http://readium.org/news/bluefire-releases-readium-based-cloudshelf-reader-app

Comment: From the Readium Press release:  "The newly launched Cloudshelf app is a separate business line from Bluefire Reader white label apps, which Bluefire will continue to offer and maintain."

Comment: **@idiotprogrammer** The latest versions of Bluefire Reader and ADE 4.5/RMSDK 12.5 are both [based on the Readium SDK](http://readium.org/about/applications-based-on-readium) and Bluefire Productions is also an [Adobe RMSDK licensee](http://blogs.adobe.com/aemmobile/reader-mobile-licensees).